# Can I work for as a software engineer for a company that also does pornography?

Tags: halal-haram, work, software

I am a software engineer in India and striving Muslim. Recently I got new job offer from a company and after all the legal clarification, I accepted the job offer. But recently I heard from my friend the company also does work for a pornography website.  My work is not going to relate with that in any manner but that company do the work in that field.

Please suggest me with the authentic hadith or Quran Ayath. Should I work with them or not?

Answer (score 1):

Asalaam alaikum

**Our Lord, give us in this world [that which is] good and in the Hereafter [that which is] good and protect us from the punishment of the Fire.[2:201]**

it is incumbent upon us muslims to strive for the betterment of this world as well as the aakhirah. we as muslims must always try avoid anything that goes against quran and authentic sunnah. we must not entertain anything that would displease our Rabb.

pornography is haram in islam and there is no doubt about it. your company is involved in it and now you know it. its rational that as human beings we first go through a phase called justification when defending something we want or when trying to avoid something which you may believe is not good for you. its the reason why you have said "I already ask the co. that I am not going to support any HARAM work in any manner either directly or indirectly. and they are agree with term and condition. Hope I am clear". you must understand that sometimes there is a very fine line between halal and haram. you may think that you are doing the right thing just because it is something you are afraid to let go.

**....But perhaps you hate a thing and it is good for you; and perhaps you love a thing and it is bad for you. And Allah Knows, while you know not.[2:216]**

you may still think that you are just an insignificant individual working in a different department in this company that supports pornography (we don't know to which extent or what other haram acts/businesses they might be involved in), so it wont affect me. Allah the mighty and sublime has warned us against this,

**And cooperate in righteousness and piety, but do not cooperate in sin and aggression. And fear Allah ; indeed, Allah is severe in penalty.[5:2]**

knowing and not doing anything to avoid it when you can is supporting/helping that cause. beware of the following hadith of wine, as it clearly explains the context of your question, insha Allah.

> It was narrated from Ibn ‘Umar that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said:
> “Wine is cursed from ten angles: The wine itself, the one who squeezes (the grapes etc), the one for whom it is squeezed, the one who sells it, the one who buys it, the one who carries it, the one to whom it is carried, the one who consumes its price, the one who drinks it and the one who pours it.”

Grade :Hasan (Darussalam)
Reference : Sunan Ibn Majah 3380

wine itself is haram and can you see how the 9 people are involved in the process.so ask yourself who are you here?....knowing something is haram and entertaining it, when you have choice and means to avoid it is not acceptable.

> Abu Sa'eed Al-Khudri  may  Allaah  be  pleased  with  him said: “I heard the Prophet  sallallaahu  `alayhi  wa  sallam ( may  Allaah exalt his mention ) saying: "Whoever amongst you sees an evil, he should change it with his hand (i.e. physically), if he is unable, then he should change it with his tongue (i.e. verbally) and if he is unable, then he should change it with his heart (by detesting it in his heart) and that is the weakest level of faith." [Muslim]

Halal rizq is a very critical matter. Halal rizq Isn't just a halal income, Halal food or Halal sustenance, it's so much more than that. It has an effect on one's spiritual state as well as one's acts of Ibadah. Consuming haram rizq can affect one's Deen and one may not even realize it.

may Allah the mighty and sublime grant you mercy and guide you to the straight path.

Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

Its impossible a submited person being a leader of a pornography company since we have the advise to not accept desires as deities, pornography promotes exactly that  [25:43](https://quran.com/25/43) The hypocrit answer is saying technically yes if the persons in this company are all submited to God. Lets not be fool here. [4:43](https://quran.com/4/43), [4:44](https://quran.com/25/44)

> Have you seen the one who takes as his god his own desire? Then would
>   you be responsible for him?
>   Or do you think that most of them hear or reason? They are not except
>   like livestock. Rather, they are [even] more astray in [their] way.

In my view the one of the main Messages is encouraging you, to submit yourself to God accepting its Revelation, and if you are submited, you must follow the Book and take in consideration its warnings and stories, since even a true muslim has its journey full of tests and rewards.

[57:29](https://quran.com/59/29)

> [This is] so that the People of the Scripture may know that they are
>   not able [to obtain] anything from the bounty of Allah and that [all]
>   bounty is in the hand of Allah ; He gives it to whom He wills. And
>   Allah is the possessor of great bounty.

With that idea in mind we can use some math to make comparasions  a way can balance companies that are **very worst**, **more less worst** or **better than worst companies**. And we can even think that pornography its a way to make desbelievers astray. Since He guides or the inverse who He wants.

[27:62](https://quran.com/27/62)

> Is He [not best] who responds to the desperate one when he calls upon
>   Him and removes evil and makes you inheritors of the earth? Is there a
>   deity with Allah ? Little do you remember.

The Quran explicitly denies adultery [4:15](https://quran.com/4/15), and God rules in the Book the way that woman should present in public in a form that would be hypocrit to think that its right working in the pornographic industry, I think pornography increases the some sort of adultery in a global scale as its informed [here](http://www.christiantruthcenter.com/adultery/), and you can measure adultery in the same way that you can measure if its better to work in this or that company .

> Those who commit unlawful sexual intercourse of your women - bring
>   against them four [witnesses] from among you. And if they testify,
>   confine the guilty women to houses until death takes them or Allah
>   ordains for them [another] way.

[32:4](https://quran.com/32/4)

> It is Allah who created the heavens and the earth and whatever is
>   between them in six days; then He established Himself above the
>   Throne. You have not besides Him any protector or any intercessor; so
>   will you not be reminded?

Remind, reflect, above certain topics with the help of the Revelation and submit yourself and fear only God. If you are a muslim remind yourself that God gived to you science and you should reflect and choose what you will do with that science, because He warned you about the Day Of Resurrection:

[32:25](https://quran.com/32/25)

> Indeed, your Lord will judge between them on the Day of Resurrection
>   concerning that over which they used to differ.

Answer (score 0):

In short: I think you are not allowed to work with them, since you help them indirectly/directly...

Comment: While this seems obvious, your argument will be more persuasive if backed up with quotes or other evidences from quran and hadith.

Answer (score -1):

> "I already ask the co. that I am not going to support any HARAM work in any manner either directly or indirectly. and they are agree with term and condition. Hope I am clear. "

So this job of your not in condition of haram. As you said you are living  in a country which is not ruled by Islamic rules. You can prevent yourself from involving haram but you can not change or force every people.

As you said

> "Every work have some HARAM component"

If you dig enough, you can possible find a thing or stuff which is considered as haram in Islam. In your case, you did declare your working conditions within Islam and they agreed.
In this perspective it's okay to work with them.

Comment: brother, please try to add reference from Quran and Sunnah when you give answers.

Answer (score -2):

I think it's wrong to work related to this we should prevent ourselves the rizk is upto allah so believe in allah and avoid doing this.